# How do I transform new data with H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator GLRM)?

Tags: h2o

It looks like H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator (GLRM) is exactly what I want.  I used to transform my training set data.  My idea was then to build a classifier based on the new features (archetypes)

What's not clear (after looking at the documentation and examples), is how one would apply the trained GLRM model to new data to get a new data frame to pass onto the classifier model trained with archetype data.  Trying to use GLRM predict in an obvious way doesn't seem to work.

My hunch is this must be possible.  Based on the Linear Algebra equation (where A is the original data, X is the matrix of new archetypes and Y is the transforming matrix):

A=XY

So that

A*inverse(Y) = X

[Sorry I don't have enough points to add **GLRM** as a Tag]

```
glrm = h2o.estimators.glrm.H2OGeneralizedLowRankEstimator(
    k = 100,  # Reduce to top 100 features
                                           transform = "STANDARDIZE",
                                           loss = "Quadratic",
                                           regularization_x = "Quadratic",
                                           regularization_y = "L1",
                                           gamma_x = 0.25,
                                           gamma_y = 0.5,
                                           max_iterations = 100


)

glrm.train(
    training_frame = df
)

# Try to transform the original data with the trained GLRM
pg = glrm.predict(df)
```

Results in this error:

```
EnvironmentError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_96037b3ddc5e3e48d5273428d2fa43ee failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not make vectors of different length compatible!
stacktrace: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not make vectors of different length compatible!
at water.fvec.Frame.makeCompatible(Frame.java:1390)
at water.fvec.Frame.makeCompatible(Frame.java:1378)
at water.fvec.Frame.bulkAdd(Frame.java:591)
at water.fvec.Frame.add(Frame.java:576)
at water.fvec.Frame.add(Frame.java:630)
at hex.glrm.GLRMModel.reconstruct(GLRMModel.java:225)
at hex.glrm.GLRMModel.predictScoreImpl(GLRMModel.java:247)
at hex.Model.score(Model.java:1118)
at water.api.ModelMetricsHandler$1.compute2(ModelMetricsHandler.java:352)
at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1256)
at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: I don't think this is currently supported, but there is a workaround - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/SYT-Lg1QCAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  Using GLRM, you decompose a matrix A = XY and you perform clustering on X.  For a new dataset, ANew, you need to get your new XNew.  To do this, you perform XNew = ANew * inverse(Y).  However, if your dataset contains categorical columns, GLRM will first expand the categorical columns using one hot encoding which will increase the number of columns in your original dataset.  In addition, it will move all categorical columns to the front, then perform one hot encoding.  And then, it will perform GLRM on AOneHot = XY.  Hence, when you try XNew = ANew * inverse(Y), you have the dimension mismatch.  The way to do this is to perform one hot encoding on your categorical columns on ANew and then apply inverse(Y).   Hope this helps.  Wendy

Comment: Is anyone here able able to demonstrate how i can generate the XNew. I am having the same challenge, and not smart enough to get the product of Anew * Inverse(Y). I'm trying to cluster new datasets on the arch features from trained GLRM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72753783/how-do-i-generate-the-archetypes-of-new-dataset-from-the-glrm-predict-function